# Reading from a file in Idris

Tags: functional-programming, monads, ghci, idris

what's the preferred idiomatic way of reading files in Idris? For example I'm trying to read numbers from a file map that to Int values and sum everything. Input file

`5 3 4 6 12`

```
import Data.String

myCast: Maybe Integer -> Integer
myCast Nothing = 0
myCast (Just val) = val


sumNums: String -> Integer
sumNums s = sum (map myCast (map parseInteger (words s)))
```

and I'm interested mostly in the reading part

```
main : IO ()
main = do
  (Right content) <- readFile "input.txt" | (Left err) => printLn err
  printLn (sumNums content)
```

What is the proper way to deal with `Either` / `Maybe` here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the book](https://www.manning.com/books/type-driven-development-with-idris) and [the docs](https://www.idris-lang.org/docs/1.0/prelude_doc/docs/Prelude.File.html)

```
main : IO ()
main = do file <- readFile "input.txt"
          case file of
               Right content => printLn (sumNums content)
               Left err => printLn err
```

the `<-` allows us to act directly on the `Either` of the `IO (Either FileError String)`. We then case split on the possible values, printing them in each case